# Duplicate "This post has been deleted and is no longer viewable" banner when reviewing a first answer

Tags: bug, review, deleted-posts, duplication

When reviewing a first answer, you *only* see the answer and its comments on the 'Answer' tab; nothing related to the question. However, if both the question and the answer get deleted while reviewing, you'll see a double "This post has been deleted and is no longer viewable" banner. Could this banner be deduplicated?

[image]